# Своя интернет-страница

Tags: веб-программирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Вот многие люди, которые держали свои игровые сервера, делали себе интернет-страницу. Я бы тоже очень хотел сделать себе, да вот не могу. Что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле всё банально. Вам нужно приобрести хостинг (место для хранения сайта. мегабайт 50-100 для начала хватит). Причем можно взять как бесплатный хостинг (не очень - много рекламы, в некоторых случаях от рекламы может поехать сайт, да и условия в целом зачастую так себе), так и неплохой дешевый. Так же, если возьмете сайт на платном хостинге, то надо будет купить домен (например .com, .ru, .net и т.п.). Домены тоже различаются по стоимости, и, в принципе тот же домен .ru можно найти за 100-150 рублей. Домен покупается на год, потом можно продлить ещё на год (естественно, заплатив:) ).
Да, забыл - хостинг надо искать с поддержкой MySQL и PHP.
Дальше качаете какие-нибудь движки CMS/Дневников/форумов и ставите их. Ставить их проще простого, практически автоматически. Потом уже в настройке самого сайта из админки разобраться будет совсем не сложно. Из бесплатных неплохих движков могу подсказать livestreet, wordpress. Из платных DLE, Joomla, и т.д. из форумных платных vBulletin, IPB, и т.д. 
*(По секрету скажу, что их в инете и бесплатно можно скачать, просто зачастую в их лицензионном соглашении написано, что если у вас "крякнутая" версия, то просто вам будет отказано в официальной поддержке)*.

Вот, в принципе и всё. Если что забыл, потом допишу. Вообще по каждому из этих шагов в инете огромное множество информации, ищите. Это всё очень просто.

Comment: Я тут парюсь с WEB обвязками, я нашел для себя удачный, красивый, понравившейся для меня фон, и хочу его установить, но никак((( для этого нашел программу AppServ, на сервере l2portal, там есть мануал по настройке, вроде все сделал, как написано. Но не фурычит что-то... Вот сижу голову ломаю... А за остольное спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - http://ucoz.ru.

Answer (score 0):

Вам понадобится какой-нибудь хостинг, написать эту страничку самому, либо привлечь сторонних разработчиков, и разместить на вашем хостинге.

Так же есть бесплатные средства, такие как ucoz.ru. Там может создать страничку даже неопытный пользователь.

Answer (score 0):

Apache + PHP + MariaDB ман по установке php был на php.ru/install
Там же ман по установке апача, вот по MariaDB придется погуглить, мускуль не рекомендую ставить.

Answer (score 0):

поконкретней бы вопрос. для чего страница, для чего сервер. 
"вот хочу, да не могу", а зачем?
если потренироваться - для этого можно на локалке поставить сервер.
если надо клансайт сделать - есть уже готовые сервисы, типа того же юкоза.
если страничку васи пупкина, ничего проще, чем завести страничку в соц сети нету.

Answer (score 0):

Советую юзать готовые CMS, типа Joomla Wordpress и тд

Comment: Я бы MKPortal рекомендовал он как раз для таких целей подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно своя страничка по типу блога, то вам на [blog.ru](http://blog.ru), [tut.by](http://tut.by) - там тоже можно создавать блоги и т.д.